# How do I disable Visual Studio's SQL auto-formatting and class designer features?

Tags: visual-studio

How do I disable the following "unwanted features" in Visual Studio 2005/2008/2010?

1. Class Designer
2. SQL Query auto-formatting

I know [how to disable the F1 help](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2008/07/18/visual-studio-tip-disable-f1.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

2) You can't: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/480516/stop-vs2010-from-rewriting-my-sql-in-datasets

Comment: This is response for #2. Thank you. Basically microsoft says "it is by design" and "it is too risky for them to change now".