# How to disable auto formatting of SQL queries in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ms-access

I am using the "New Query" feature (aka "Query Designer") in the "Server Explorer" of VS on one of our Access databases to develop the SQL to be used in our application. 
When executing a query, VS is automatically formatting the SQL before execution. On more than one occasion I have found that this formatting turns executable SQL into something throwing an error. 
For example:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.CodeNr
FROM   (Product p INNER JOIN
        ProductPrice pp ON ((p.ID = pp.ID_Product) AND 
                            (pp.ID_Distributor = 32)))
```

If I execute this query directly in code against the Access database it works fine. 
If I enter this query in the Query Designer window and execute it, VS is turning it into:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.CodeNr
FROM   (Product p INNER JOIN
        ProductPrice pp ON p.ID = pp.ID_Product AND 
                           pp.ID_Distributor = 32)
```

and then complains that the join expression is not supported.

Is there any way to disable this auto formatting before execution? 
If not what would be a similar environment to quickly test SQL queries against an Access database?

I'm using VS2019 Community 16.2.4
The connection to the Access db is the same in the "Server Explorer" and in our application:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="db.accdb"
```

I have found this: [How do I disable Visual Studio's SQL auto-formatting and class designer features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080990/how-do-i-disable-visual-studios-sql-auto-formatting-and-class-designer-features)
which seem to indicate that it's not possible but this is 8 years old and the link doesn't work anymore.

**Update:**
Regarding my second question to find a similar environment to quickly test SQL queries: I just found [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) which supports Access databases via the "LINQ to DB" driver and allows for query input in plain SQL.